# Android - Do something *after* text is changed in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I build an android application. I have an EditText. I want to save changes (or anything else) automatically after the user change the text. 
Now I use

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

and

```
  TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     ...
    }
```

But it saves the changes after every little change (add \ remove a letter), and I want that it'll be saved only after the user finished (closed the keyboard, clicked on a different edittext, etc. ).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As Kotlin is now official android language:

```
var editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText) 

editText.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (!hasFocus) { 
           //SAVE THE DATA       
        }
}
```